# make javascript work on body instead of in js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to put my button javascript code on body of my page instead of in js file

the code you see at header it will go to js file but for now i put it at header

when i click on that button it will hide class="load_video" and play video

but i want to put it's code on body because if for some reason js file didn't load on browser, users must be able to click on button instead of waiting for 10 to play video.

that code in header is for my 10 seconds counter. it will countdown from 10 seconds when it's 0, video will start.

here's my javascript code on plnkr full code http://plnkr.co/edit/AJQOP9YO0LDOfDUBD3YR?p=preview

```
<script>
  function startChecking() { 
secondsleft -= 1e3, document.querySelector(".load_video").innerHTML = "Please Wait.. " + Math.abs(secondsleft / 1e3) + " Seconds", 0 == secondsleft && (clearInterval(interval), $(".reloadframe").show(), document.querySelector(".load_video").style.display = "none", document.querySelector(".frame_src").style.display = "", document.querySelector(".frame_src").src = document.querySelector(".frame_src").getAttribute("data-src"), $("#btn_click_to_play").hide()) 
}

function startschedule() { 
document.querySelector(".frame_src").src = "about:blank"; 
clearInterval(interval), secondsleft = threshold, document.querySelector(".load_video").innerHTML = "Please Wait.. " + Math.abs(secondsleft / 1e3) + " Seconds", interval = setInterval(function() { 
startChecking() 
}, 1e3) 
}

function resetTimer() {
    startschedule()
}
var timeout, interval, threshold = 1e4,
    secondsleft = threshold;
window.onload = function() {
    startschedule()
};
</script>
```

all that code i want to put them in js file but i only need to take out my button code to put on body.

because if it was like this, and if for some reason my s file didn't load , then no countdown starts and users won't be able to click on button.

if some one can help me here or send me chat request. appreciate it.

Comment: Firstly, can you explain what you mean a little better? It's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve. Secondly, your JS code must have syntax errors *everywhere* as you're using `,` as a line-ending character when it should be `;`

Comment: what i am trying to do is to get button code from my header code to body. in header there is countdown code and button code also included in that. and about syntax error, no there is no error the code is fine and working it's only showing error on plnkr. if you have html supported server you can test the code

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the event using the button onclick event instead of  call the startschedule function.

So your code would be:

```
  window.onload = function() {
    //startschedule()
    document.getElementById('btn_click_to_play').onclick = function(){
    $(".reloadframe").show();
    document.querySelector(".load_video").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(".frame_src").style.display = "";
    document.querySelector(".frame_src").src = document.querySelector(".frame_src").getAttribute("data-src");
    $("#btn_click_to_play").hide() ;


    }
```

You can use any function to handle the click event.

Comment: thank you caballerog , but did you understand in my code ? i think it's very complicated . can you place make it for me how you mean ? i don't have much experience in javascript

Comment: thank you. but the code didn't work . may i start chat with you?

Answer (score 0):

If that is your question, just use `<script type="text/javascript"> YOUR CODE </script>` at the end of your body.